# How to fixed and center image on media screen @media (max-width: 480px)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using owl carousel and i don't want the image to be squeezed or compressed on mobile size

```
   <!--=========================slider===========================-->
  <div id="main-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item text-center">
      <img src="img/front_girl1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item text-center">
      <img src="img/front_girl_3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item text-center">
      <img src="img/front_girl_2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS on media screen 1200px

```
#main-slider .item img{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height:700px;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

My CSS on 480px but its not working when i resize the browser it's just compressed

```
#main-slider .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:700px;
    background-position: center center fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Any suggestions ???

Comment: Your height is a fixed amount, change it to a percentage.

Comment: Change the height to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the width of the owl carousel? Also, you'll have to remove your height class or set it to auto. You could also add this:

```
.owl-carousel{
   width:100% !important;
}
```

Also if your using bootstrap you can add the classes "img-responsive" on the image to ensure it is responsive and "center-block" to have the image aligned in the center